# Multiple Clause

Tags: excel

I have a table like this

```
ID   Process  Work

A1   | 0 |       Done                                                                                                                                               
A1   | 1 |       Progress                                                                                                                                               
A2   | 0 |       Done
```

I need to output A1. Meaning ID of only that work when Process=0 and Work= 'Done'.

How do I use multiple And statements in where condition?

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: please give your expected output.and more clarification

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (process = 0 AND work = 'Done') OR (process > 0 AND Work = 'Progress')`

Comment: select Id from yourtable where  (Process=0 and Work='Done') or (Process>0 and Work='Progress')

Answer (score 0):

you can have simple Query like

```
Select * from table where (process = 0 AND work = 'Done') and  (work ='Progress' and process > 0)
```

Will definitely give you A1

Answer (score 0):

Due to your description "will output only A1 since for Process>0 A2 and A3 have Work=Done", I suppose the requirement is actually the following:

"Get only those entries with process=0 and work=done, where no other process>0 with work=done (and the same id) exists."

This could be expressed in SQL as follows:

```
select t1.* from table t1 where (t1.process = 0 AND t1.work = 'Done')
and t1.id not in (select t2.id from table t2 where t2.process > 0 and t2.work = 'Done')
```